# Why does my pie chart in Tkinter does not show?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pie-chart, matplotlib-widget

I am building an application which takes input, saves it to a CSV file and now the last basic part is to **display a pie chart of the content of the column**. The input is supposed to be about books. So, the pie chart should for example display the genre of all the books in the list.

I do not have a problem with creating the pie chart, I managed it in a separate script, I do not receive an error message either but instead have only a white field.

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import ttk
from collections import Counter

class FrontFrames:

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
    #Split the screen horizontally in two parts
        top_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="green")
        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="yellow")
        top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        bottom_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    #Creating the three top widgets
        self.tree = Label(top_frame)

        column = ("Title", "author", "year", "others")

        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(top_frame, columns=column, show='headings')
        self.treeview.heading("Title", text="Title")
        self.treeview.heading("author", text="Author")
        self.treeview.heading("year", text="Year")
        self.treeview.heading("others", text="Others")
        content = "./Note.csv"
        with open(content, 'r') as file:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
            for row in csv_reader:
                self.treeview.insert('', '0', values=(f'{row["title"]}',
                                                      f'{row["author"]}',
                                                      f'{row["year"]}',
                                                      f'{row["others"]}'))
                c = Counter(row["others"])

        header = list(c.keys())
        values = list(c.values())
        colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'y']
        f = plt.Figure(figsize=(4,4))
        #a = f.add_subplot(111)
        pie = plt.pie(values, labels=header, colors=colors, startangle=90, 
                      autopct='%.1f%%')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, top_frame)

        self.tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.treeview.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="right", fill="both")
        #self.canvas.show()
```

I commented out the line "self.canvas.show()" because I otherwise receive the **error message**:

> AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'show'

It is always told that the command must be included in order to actually display the pie chart but in a separate test where no other widget are build, the pie chart is visible. I assume that the pie chart is just hidden under another widget.

The content of the CSV would look like the following:

```
title, author, year, others, note
Everything,Nobody,2222,Fiction,This is just something of everything!
Nothing,Everybody,1111,Romance,This is nothing of anything!
Pokemon,Pikachu,1999,Fiction,Once upon time.
Lord of the rings, R.R. Jackson, 1972, Fantasy, A long story!
Harry Potter, Rowling, 1995, Fantasy, A detailed story.
Bible, Apostels, 0, Fiction, A story.
The Ring, Frank, 1980, Horror, A scary story.
1984, Orwell, 1932, Dystopia, A scary future for the past and scary present 
for us.
Pirates of the Caribbean, Brandow, 1955, Fiction, A pirate story.
```

I use Python 3.7.0

As always, thank you very much for your helpful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for `self.canvas.show`, my python interpreter tells me that `FigureCanvasTkAgg.show` is deprecated and that  I should use `draw` instead.

As for the issue with the plot, I managed to make the pie chart appear by uncommenting `a = f.add_subplot(111)` and by replacing

```
plt.pie(values, labels=header, colors=colors, startangle=90, autopct='%.1f%%')
```

by

```
a.pie(values, labels=header, colors=colors, startangle=90, autopct='%.1f%%')
```

So my guess is that your chart was displayed in the wrong figure since you weren't explicitly specifying the axes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It worked perfectly and my question is answered. May I ask what interpreter you are using? I use PyCharm.